# How to get meta value in wp_attachment_metadata

Tags: post-meta, attachments, images

I want to get `wp_attachment_metadata` in my own way. I want to separate the sizes (Thumbnail, Large, Medium, Small). The meta value on database looks like this:

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:660;s:6:"height";i:320;s:4:"file";s:39:"2013/07/debut 
-busana-muslim-new-yor.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:2:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"f 
ile";s:39:"debut-busana-muslim-new-yor-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s: 
6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s: 
4:"file";s:39:"debut-busana-muslim-new-yor-300x145.jpg";s:5:"width";i:30 
0;s:6:"height";i:145;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_met 
a";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7: 
"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:1 
2:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title"; 
s:0:"";}}
```

Well, I am stuck. I don’t know how to separate that array. Anyone knows how to separate that array in order I can get the sizes and the URL of the images.

Comment: use function - `maybe_unserialize( $the_string )` . This will convert this string into an array.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods:

1. [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

   ```
   $attachment_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_meta', true );
   ```

   Will return an `array()`:

   ```
   $width = $attachment_meta['width'];
   ```

   That `true` as the third parameter is especially important in this case, since the metadata being queried is a *serialized* array. You need to return it as single, or you're going to get an array returned, except the first item in that array will be the serialized array. Messy. Just pass `true`, and you'll get your unserialized array returned.
2. [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

   This function is sort of a wrapper for the above `get_post_meta()` call.

   ```
   $attachment_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post->ID );
   ```

In both cases, `$post` is the *attachment*, not the parent post to which the attachment is uploaded.