# how to get image url from meta value?

Tags: php

I want to get wp_attachment_metadata in my own way.   i cant get any solution for this

```
s:312:"a:3:{i:0;s:95:"http://localhost/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/kulcha-atta-300x139.png";i:1;s:84:"http://localhost/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/juices_3.png";i:2;s:91:"http://localhost/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/drop-menu-bread.png";}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a serialized **array** value in the database. WordPress serializes arrays as a way of storing structured data in the database.

You need to use [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to get the post meta data value, something like this:

```
$array = get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_data_key_name', TRUE); // add the meta data key name
```

Then, you can print the content of the `$array`:

```
print_r($array);
```

Or echo it like:

```
echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];
```

That's of course if it is an [indexed](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp) array (which you will find out when you `print_r()` it).

Comment: its not working. i get same value

Comment: Can you please show me how you are using `get_post_meta()`?

Comment: `$array = get_post_meta($post_id, 'miu_images', TRUE);
print_r($array);`

Comment: Is `$post_ids` the correct attachment ID? Your `print_r()` line is incorrect, it should be `print_r($array);` and finally, did you edit the database key value in any way manually, for example via phpmyadmin?

Comment: @yogesh The `$post_id` is the attachment ID and not the ID of the parent post to which the attachment is uploaded.

Comment: @yogesh I suggest you to, refer to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/130087/83739) answer

Comment: Yes, the `$post_id` should be the attachment ID. @MariaDanielDeepak I think this is a case of the user editing the key value manually and scrambling the serialized value. Although we will need more information first. =)

Comment: pleaes see this url [http://prntscr.com/g5t9l3]

Comment: What output do you get when you run the following: `$array = get_post_meta(430, 'miu_images', TRUE); print_r($array);` -- please post the output here.

Comment: `a:4:{i:0;s:95:"http://svirtzonewebworks.com/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/kulcha-atta-300x139.png";i:1;s:84:"http://svirtzonewebworks.com/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/juices_3.png";i:2;s:91:"http://svirtzonewebworks.com/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/drop-menu-bread.png";i:3;s:84:"http://svirtzonewebworks.com/WORDPRESS/aurra/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/masala_1.png";}`

Comment: I can see that you are using phpmyadmin. And I suspect that you have clicked on the meta value field in phpmyadmin and either edited it **or** saved it. Either one will likely scramble the serialization. Can you please do the following. Find a *different* attachment post that has this meta key and target that one using `get_post_meta()`. This way, you can confirm if this was the issue.